# Why are my uv's getting streched when not using a square ratio?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

So, I've created a mesh in Houdini, and exported it to blender. The UV's look like how you would expect in a standard square layout, but get warped whenever you use anything else. Any idea why? All I want is for it to be uniform in size so I can throw on different sized images.

Using blender 3.2.0

.blend: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-2IOlBgNY8rQC0kUlDlP3G8VJnDbGcz/view?usp=sharing

normal square layout

[image: image 1]

warped layout

[image]

Object I'm trying to make it work on

[image]

Texture nodes

[image: texture]

Comment: it's just a flat rectangular surface? why not unwrap it again?

Comment: because I have to do it in Houdini. I'm trying to create a procedural thing and only render it in blender. I don't want to unwrap every time I make a small change in houdini

Comment: i don't know much about houdini but it may be a compatibility issue? you could write a script that unwraps for you so whenever you import run the script something like `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()` then `bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
` then `bpy.ops.uv.unwrap(method='ANGLE_BASED', margin=0.001)`

Comment: Well, UV's are standardised, so I really doubt it's a compatibility thing. Pretty sure there's just a setting somewhere that I don't know of. also, the same behaviour happens when unwrapping in blender

Answer (score 3):

You have some UV scaling in the nodes, so that texture 46% smaller than UV

[image]

Then you change Image with different aspect ratio, it is designed to be stretched. This is because UV's coordinates are written in percents, not in pixels. This allows to switch between resolution versions without having problems.

If you open the front view and press <kbd>U</kbd> ⇾ Project from view, It will give you the right aspect ratio according to the image in the shader.

Comment: that was just so I could see it. it's uniform in all vectors so it doesn't matter. If I set it to 1 the same thing happens

Comment: can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Blend exchange wont upload for some reason
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-2IOlBgNY8rQC0kUlDlP3G8VJnDbGcz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Location 0 and scale 1 gives me correct result.

Comment: no, it just looks like that.  if you zoom out, it's actually stretched into a square. I'm trying to get it into the aspect ratio of the image

Comment: Then you change Image with different aspect ratio, it is designed to be stretched. This is because UV's coordinates are written in percents, not in pixels. This allows to switch between resolution versions without having problems.

Comment: is there a way to make it calculate with pixels?

Comment: If you open the front view and press U ⇾ Project from view, It will give you the right aspect ratio according to the image in the shader.

Comment: Or make images with same aspect ratio